# mysql (5.5.5-10.2.14-MariaDB)

Tags: mariadb, moodle

mysql (5.5.5-10.2.14-MariaDB)
version 5.5.31 is required and you are running 5.5.5.10.2.14 how can I fix this issue, please. I am trying to upgrade to Moodle 3.4.2+ (Build: 20180322)

Comment: The problem is literally in the error.

Comment: Hello Mehdi, I got it fixed, thanks to Anujna

Comment: Either share the solution, or delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

Change "mysql" or "mysqli" by "mariadb" on config.php